# Show ProgressDialog while loading AppState from file

Tags: android, android-activity, state, activity-lifecycle

When my activity is being closed, I serialize the application state data to file to give me a chance to reload the state if the app gets killed by the system.

This approach (saving and restoring state) works fine. But, sometimes, when the process was killed, and depending on the amount of data to load, the loading state process can least some seconds to complete.

So, I can't load the state on a separeted thread because my activity will crash if the data isn't there on the onLoad.

So, I'd like to display a progress dialogue while loading the content, but, ensure that the Activity's onLoad method will be called only after the loading state process.

Does anybody knows how could I achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.. could you Override the `onLoad()` function, then add a boolean that states whether you're displaying the dialog or not.  If the dialog is being displayed (the boolean is true), don't let `onLoad()` do anything; otherwise, carry on as usual.  That way once the dialog is dismissed, you can set the boolean to false again, and if `onLoad()` isn't called by default afterwards, perhaps you could manually call it?  This is just an idea.

In other words: the dialog can be displayed using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  In the `onPreExecute()` method, set the boolean to true, do everything you need in `doInBackground()`, and in `onPostExecute()`, set the boolean to false and call `onLoad()`.

On a side note... do you mean `onCreate()` or `onResume()`?  I've actually not heard of `onLoad()`, unless this is a function you created.